# How to hook up the UINavigationControllerDelegate to the navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

**ANSWER: simple syntax error - when setting the delegate, it should read SomeNavigationController.delegate = self, not SomeNavigationController.navigationController?.delegate = self**

Below is the base view controller where the navigation controller is created. I declared self as its delegate and conformed to the delegate's protocol in an extension to that view controller and created an object as the custom animator. But the view controllers within this navigation stack do not adopt this animation; what am I missing?

Does any code need to exist in the root view controller of this navigation stack or within the view controllers that are being pushed and popped in this stack? Or does all the custom animation code belong here (in the view controller where the navigation controller is created) and I'm just missing something?

**View Controller where UINavigationController is created**

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        buildNavigationController()
    }

    func buildNavigationController() {
        let SomeNavigationControllerRoot = SomeViewController()
        let SomeNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SomeNavigationControllerRoot)
        SomeNavigationController.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(SomeNavigationController.view)
    }

}

extension BaseViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return CustomAnimator()
    }

}

class CustomAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1.0
    }


    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)

        containerView.addSubview(toViewController!.view)

        toViewController!.view.alpha = 0.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            toViewController!.view.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: { finished in
            let cancelled = transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!cancelled)
        })

    }

}
```

**Root View Controller in UINavigationController stack**

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func pushToNext() {
        let randomViewController = randomViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(randomViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess instead of delegate set transition delegate. toViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom transitions you need to apply transitioningDelegate
Set the view controller’s transitioningDelegate to your custom class and return custom animation controllers.